# Are large cardinal types always club classes?

Tags: large-cardinals

Given a particular type of large cardinal (Mahlo, Ramsey, Vopenka, etc) is it always the case that the class of such cardinals is closed and unbounded, that is if  $\mathcal L\subseteq On$ is a class of large cardinals according to a given type/definition then is it the always the case that:-

1) $\mathcal L$ is a proper class.

2) For all $\alpha\in On$ there is a $\beta\in\mathcal L$ such that $\alpha\le\beta$.

3) For all $A\subseteq\mathcal L$ we have $\sup A\in\mathcal L$.

The reason I ask is because I would like to know if even those large cardinals defined by elementary embeddings like superstrong cardinals also have a purely set-theoretic characterisation.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to be making some sort of additional assumptions?  After all, there might not exist any large cardinals, and then $\mathcal{L}$ would be empty.

Comment: Strong cardinals can be characterized with extenders.

Comment: The reason for my question is that for philosophical reasons I think any large cardinal type, say type L (eg. superstrong), should have an intrinsic definition. Those large cardinals defined extrinsically via elementary embeddings of models should at least have an equivalent intrinsic definition, otherwise they are meta-cardinals living outside of set theory in the heads of logicians using who knows what "bootstrap" set theory. This question re intrinsic vs extrinsic definitions is then "If type L large cardinals exist, not matter how defined, is there an equivalent intrinsic definition".

Comment: Hi Asaf, can you point me to something on extenders? You can probably see from my question that I was wondering if, assuming they exist, large cardinals of type $\mathcal L$ can always be characterised as fixed points of a normal function $L:On\to On$ perhaps with additional properties in a large enough set/class theory,

Comment: @MarkKortink As my answer shows, any large cardinal notion implying regularity can *never* be so characterized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tl;dr, **No**, they are not.

---

Let's leave aside the issue of **unboundedness**, although this does pose a problem: as Eric Wofsey points out, it is consistent with ZFC that $\mathcal{L}$ is empty for any large cardinal property $\mathcal{L}$ (that's sort of implied by the phrase "large cardinal"), and - for all the properties I'm aware of, at least - *existence* does not imply *frequent existence*, in the sense that e.g. it is consistent with ZFC that there are exactly 12 inaccessible cardinals.

We could conceivably get around this by assuming that lots of large cardinals of various types exist. This isn't as trivial as it may sound: for example, if there is a measurable cardinal, then there are infinitely many inaccessible cardinals, and if there is (say) a supercompact cardinal then there are *unboundedly* many inaccessible cardinals. Let's instead focus on the **closed** part. It's here that things go very wrong, in what I think is a fatal way: it is in fact essentially never the case that the set of large cardinals of a certain type is closed!

Why? Well, any club contains lots of elements of cofinality $\omega$ (exercise), but no uncountable regular cardinal has cofinality $\omega$; and almost every large cardinal property that I'm aware of demands regularity.

---

As to your question about *defining* large cardinals: this is a good suspicion to have! Indeed, on the face of it definitions like "The critical point of some nontrivial elementary embedding $j: V\rightarrow M$" seem unformalizable in the language of set theory. Let me say a few words about this. **Note: this isn't really my area, so I hope I don't screw anything up. Inner model theorists, please correct me if necessary!**

It turns out that basically all of the large cardinals defined in such a way can be given nice, ZFC-expressible definitions. For example, what I wrote above is the definition of a *measurable* cardinal, which can also be defined as "A cardinal admitting a countably complete ultrafilter." **EDIT: this is wrong - that's the definition of an *Ulam measurable* cardinal. Obviously these are closed upwards. A cardinal $\kappa$ is measurable if there is a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$.** It turns out that this approach generalizes: very large large cardinal properties can be defined in terms of either *ultrafilters* satisfying certain combinatorial properties, or *extenders*, which are basically sets of ultrafilters satisfying certain fancy properties (see [The ABCs of Mice](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2687795.pdf) by Schimmerling).

As a taste of this, let me point out that every elementary embedding $j: V\rightarrow M$ yields an ultrafilter $U$ on its critical point $crit(j)=\kappa$ as follows: $$U=\{X: \kappa\in j(X)\}.$$ So this is a way to "collapse" the (class-sized) elementary embedding down to a (set-sized) object. It turns out that this captures a lot of the behavior of $j$, and is very roughly what lets us express this sort of definition in ZFC.